# MQSeries and Delphi

Tags: delphi, websphere, ibm-mq

Are there any (preferable free and open) components or examples out there for integrating to IBM MQSeries from Delphi?

**Edit** Looks like IBM provide a unit http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24007060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in 1997, I wrote the PC part of a communication layer between PC and AS/400 (the AS/400 part was written in COBOL by someone else).

We didn't use MQSeries because (back then) it was too slow and stateless, so we went for SNA APPC in stead.

Since then [MQSeries.net](http://www.mqseries.net) has became a great source on MQseries info, including quite a few [Delphi MQseries threads](http://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+site:www.mqseries.net).

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

The provided unit looks pretty bare-bones. Well it'll work, but it would be nicer if there were working examples.  I've done this with C (AIX/Unix) and VB6, and was easily able to expand the samples into working code. If you can read C or VB, get those examples and build yourself a pair of working command-line utilities for MQPut and MQGet, working with stdin and stdout. Then you'll be able to work with queues, send/dump test messages, etc..

I worked with MQSeries about 10-12 years ago, and loved it.

Answer (score 0):

The open source [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) integration framework supports IBM WebSphere MQ (aka MQSeries).

A list of included components is here:

http://camel.apache.org/components.html

The components offer protocols like FTP, HTTP, POP, SMTP and XMPP which can be used to connect the MQSeries broker with Delphi applications.

Apache Camel is easy to set up and configure and is in active development.

Another option would be the [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing)-MQSeries Bridge. MSMQ is included in all current Windows versions.